# Differentiability,Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a continuously differentiable function,f:R to R such that inf_(for all x belonging to R) f'(x)>0.Prove that there exists some a belonging to R such that f(a)=0.

Its clear that f is strictly monotonically increasing function,but the main problem I am facing is to show that it will cut the x axis once.I am having a clear geometrical view how it will be but not getting how to prove it analytically.Any help would be truly appreciated.

Function like e^x is also strictly increasing but its inf of f'(x)=0.

Comment: Can you figure out what the limit of $f$ must be at $\infty$ and at $-\infty$, and why?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, $f$ is strictly increasing. If $f$ were bounded as $x\longrightarrow\infty$, then $\lim\limits_{x\longrightarrow\infty}f(x)$ would exist (eg. because increasing bounded sequences converge), and hence $\inf\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f'(x)$ would vanish (this follows by applying the mean value theorem and letting $x\longrightarrow +\infty$). So $f(x)\longrightarrow +\infty$ is unbounded as $x\longrightarrow +\infty$, and similarly $f(x)\longrightarrow -\infty$ as $x\longrightarrow -\infty$. Then you just apply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I got you,Thanks a lot.